# Calculating the evaporation rate of water

Tags: thermodynamics, evaporation

I'm tying to calculate how much water would evaporate when air of particular temperature and humidity and flow rate is forced on a surface containing water at a particular temperature and calculate the enthalpy change and find temperature drop of the air.

This is a simple question which can be found answer for from some educational website, but I don't know what keywords to do a google search with. What should I search in google to find the relevant details?

Comment: Would you settle for a book reverence (not online)?

Comment: Any resources are welcome.

Comment: Mass Transfer Operations by Treybel